# Embedded entity not displaying in Drupal 8.6.17 with Embed and Media Gallery installed

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I followed the instructions [on this page](https://www.webwash.net/managing-media-assets-using-core-media-in-drupal-8/#) to add the Media module to my Ckeditor. I did everything according to the instructions, additionally I added to the list of allowed entities `<drupal-entity data-*>` and yet, the image/entity does not actually display when rendering on the front-end of the site.

this is the entity tag:
`<drupal-entity data-embed-button="assets" data-entity-embed-display="entity_reference:entity_reference_entity_id" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="e9884625-791a-4362-92f7-0c56c9b928c3"></drupal-entity>`

What else can I check?